# Invoking Browser via application Icon Like Youtube Application Without Showing My Application

Tags: browser, blackberry-10, invoke, cascade, invocation

i want to invoke browser with a specific url like youtube application. I've try using Navigator Invoke but, its show my application. i dont want to show my application just show browser when user click the application icon, can anybody help me please ..

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your main() in main.cpp

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://example.com",QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

But you **MUST** remove (comment) the following lines:

```
new ApplicationUI(&app);

return Application::exec();
```

Otherwise application will open anyway

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why its only open the browser and not load the url ?